# How do I change database charset when using `wpdb`

Tags: wp-query, encoding

I have a separate connection to connect to another DB with this code of line:

```
$wpdb = new wpdb(STATYBA_USER, STATYBA_PASS, STATYBA_DB, STATYBA_HOST);
```

and it has another DB charset (`latin1` instead of `utf8`), so how can I change the charset without changing `DB_CHARSET` constant in `wp_config.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the wpdb `set_charset` method ([more info here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/set_charset/)).

example use:

```
$statyba_wpdb = new wpdb(STATYBA_USER, STATYBA_PASS, STATYBA_DB, STATYBA_HOST);
$statyba_wpdb->set_charset($statyba_wpdb->dbh, 'utf8');
```

Hope that helps.